# When is the PMI value good or bad?

Tags: feature-selection

Pointwise mutual information is calculated by this formula $pmi(x;y) = log(p(x,y)/p(x)p(y))$ , my question now is, When is this pmi good and when is it bad. I know if the value is low it is bad, but when is it possible to assume there is some decent associations between x and y ? Or do I have to determine this threshold myself (experimentally) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information), "PMI is zero if X and Y are independent and PMI maximizes when X and Y are perfectly associated". It is also mentioned that "Pointwise mutual information can be normalized between [-1,+1] resulting in -1 (in the limit) for never occurring together, 0 for independence, and +1 for complete co-occurrence."

So, based on the normalized variant, we can search for those features that well get a score close to +1 with the target variable (highly correlated). However, I am not aware of how PMI is different from MI on which methods such as [mRMR](http://penglab.janelia.org/proj/mRMR/) is based.